# Concatenate HTML code to Object in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular16

I have an object for which I need to pass my HTML code to it and use the same object value on frontend Angular 16

In .ts file Object:

```
htmlMF = '<select id="testType" name="testType" formControlName="testType"><option>Male</option><option>Female</option></select>';
name = 'xyz';
obj = {
   name: this.name,
   gender: this.htmlMF,
}
```

Frontend in .html File:

```
<span> {{ obj.gender }} </span>
<span> {{ obj.name }} </span>
```

So, **obj.gender** is printing a tag as it in the variable instead of actual dropdown with options.

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-innerhtml-binding-angular

Comment: @cmgchess this is printing only option values that is Male and Female instead of complete HTML dropdown.

Comment: hmm  yeah i also tried and it didnt render the select box

Comment: only thing i found out was to set it through ViewChild. by putting a ref `<span #selectTag></span>`

Comment: @cmgchess thanks for reply, but didn't work as per expectations. Still searching other solution if anything is available.